# Magic link [reprex] doesn't render in iOS App

Tags: bug, ios-app, magic-links

I searched but couldn't find this reported. The magic link [reprex], documented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331), doesn't render in comments on the iOS app, you just see `[reprex]`

- App version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone11,6)
- OS Version: Version 12.2 (Build 16E227)

Added screen grab of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356913)

[image: SO screengrab]

Comment: Can confirm. It doesn't work on the Android app either. I've been wondering why people keep using `[reprex]` when it doesn't render as a link. `[mcve]` still works though.

Comment: Reprex is pronounceable, so it’s easier to remember. Also `mcve` can get autocorrected to `move`. Feel free to edit the question to add the Android app version info and tag.